# Constructing params for Rest Api call issue

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have sample Python code and i am trying to construct and populate Rest API request parameters.

Headers and Authorization params are working fine but i am not sure how to translate below mention "QueryBands" and "data" variable for my Rest request using rest client.

```
queryBands = {} 
queryBands['appName'] = 'MyApp' 
queryBands['version'] = '1.0' 

# Setting request fields, including SQL. 

    data = {} 
    data['query'] = 'SELECT * from db limit 5' 
    data['queryBands'] = queryBands 
    data['format'] = 'array' 
    request = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(data), headers) 
    try: 
      response = urllib2.urlopen(request);
```

Should i need to declare new variables or pass these values as "body" while doing Rest api call?

I am using chrome advance rest-client. But it could be any rest client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json 
queryBands = {} 
queryBands['applicationName'] = 'MyApp'
queryBands['version'] = '1.0' 


data = {} 
data['query'] = 'SELECT * from db limit 5' 
data['queryBands'] = queryBands 
data['format'] = 'array' 

print(json.dumps(data))
```